# rxjs retryWhen promise is resolved

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm implementing an Angular service which calls a server for data. In every call I need to pass a token which lasts about a minute and then I need to map the response to get an specific field. So if my main call fails I need to call again for a token, wait for the response and then retry my first call, is there an easy way of doing this? Here are my two approaches (neither of them work propertly):

```
return this.http.post(url,
  firstCallText(this.token), { 
  responseType: 'text',
  headers
 })
  .pipe(
    map((xmlString: string) => {
      let asJson = this.xmlStringToJson(xmlString);
      return asJson["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["Response"]["#text"];
    }),
    catchError(async err=>{
      await this.http.post(url,
      getToken(),
      { 
        responseType: 'text',
        headers
      }).pipe(map((xmlString: string) => {
        let asJson = this.xmlStringToJson(xmlString);
        this.token = asJson["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["Response"]["Token"]["#text"];
      })).toPromise()
      return EMPTY
    }),
    retry()
  )
```

This first method fails because the retry() gets called before the new token is received.
My second approach:

```
return this.http.post(url,
  firstCallText(this.token), { 
  responseType: 'text',
  headers
 })
  .pipe(
    map((xmlString: string) => {
      let asJson = this.xmlStringToJson(xmlString);
      return asJson["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["Response"]["#text"];
    }),
    retryWhen((errors) =>{
       this.http.post(url,
        getToken(),
        { 
          responseType: 'text',
          headers
        }).pipe(map((xmlString: string) => {
          let asJson = this.xmlStringToJson(xmlString);
          this.token = asJson["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["Response"]["Token"]["#text"];
        })).toPromise()
        return EMPTY          
    })
  )
```

The second one doesn´t retry correctly, I don't want to set a delay because the token call might be shorter or longer.

Comment: Your first approach might work if you drop the async/toPromise and simply return the http observable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are facing here is that the `retry` mimics the source without it's errors, where you actually want to handle the error itself.

So my suggestion is to extend your `catchError` opertaor in such a manner that it by itself handled the "failing" case and resumes the operation, for fetching data from the server.

Here is a pseudo code solution

```js
// Answer for rxjs retryWhen promise is resolved  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061841/rxjs-retrywhen-promise-is-resolved
const {interval, of, catchError} = rxjs;
const { switchMap, tap } = rxjs.operators;

// Start of Mock for your backednd
// requestToBeValidatedWithToken will either return success meassage whenver the token is valid or throw an error when the token has expired
let token = 0;
const requestToBeValidatedWithToken = () => {
  if (token < 0) {
    throw 'Expired token';
  }
  return of('Validated request suceeds');
};
// this mocks the refresh token logic
const fetchNewToken = () => {
  token = 3;
  return of('This refreshes the token');
};
// Timer that will invalidate your token
interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
  token--;
  if (token < 0) {
    console.log('BE message: Token has expired');
  }
});
// End of Mock for your backednd

// Start of rxjs pseudo code
// This will mock your base request stream, imaginge as the request is made each seconds
const methodInYourService = () => {
  const httpCall = interval(1000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      return requestToBeValidatedWithToken();
    }),
    catchError((e) => {
      // This checks makes sure that only the "Expired token" case is handled so that you dont end in infinite loop
      if (e === 'Expired token') {
        console.log('Fire refresh token request', e);
        return fetchNewToken().pipe(
          tap(() => console.log('save your token as you recieve it')),
          switchMap(() => httpCall))
      }
      return e;
    })
  );
  return httpCall;
};

// This is the code inside your component, e.g. the place where you subscribe for the data
methodInYourService().subscribe(
  (x) => {
    console.log(x, 'fin');
  },
  (e) => {
    console.log('Will never come here, as we are handling the error');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

You can find working pseudo code solution here
[Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hxsw53?devtoolsheight=50)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although the of operator is now deprecated, I switched that to scheduled() as the [deprecation notes](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/scheduler-argument) says.